# Are there any way to set the UITableView section header color in iOS 7 directly rather creating a new UIView

Tags: uitableview, ios7

UITableView's section headers are less identifiable in iOS 7. Are there any way to set the UITableView section header color in iOS 7 directly rather creating a new UIView.

[image]

Note: I found some solutions by creating a new UIView in,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but I really wanted to keep the Apple's properties except color. Are there any way to do it without this method.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Implement `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` and update the view that you are passed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *v = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    v.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

(assuming that you supplied a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instance in your implementation for `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`)

Comment: @AlexStone, thanks for the edit, but be careful about casting `UIView *` to a subclass (particularly when answering questions ;-) )

Comment: You don't need to implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`as your answer seems to say.

Comment: `tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]` didn't work (gave gray header), only this helped.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Swift 3 the way is to achieve it via UITableViewDelegate method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView  {
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be: headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .gray

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can set **font size, font style and Header background** also.

There are have 2 method for this:

**First Method**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section{
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
        header.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        header.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans-Regular" size:12];
        [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
```

**Second Method**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
//    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 8, 320, 20);
    myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans-Regular" size:12];
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@",[self tableView:FilterSearchTable titleForHeaderInSection:section]];

    myLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    myLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [headerView addSubview:myLabel];
    return headerView;
}
```